# Rails: SQL Error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm getting a SQL error with this:

`Model:`

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :entry

    attr_accessible :body

    validates :user_id, :presence => true
    validates :entry_id, :presence => true
    validates :body, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 10, :maximum => 5000}  #spam/stupid protection

    default_scope :order => 'comments.created at sec'
end
```

`Controller`

```
  def show
        @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
            @comments = @entry.comments.all
  ...  
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @entry }
    end
  end
```

The view is a simple:

```
<% if @entry.state > 2 %>
    <section id="comments"> 
        <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
...loop some stuff...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want `:order => 'comments.created_at desc'`, not `sec`.

Comment: Yup. You got it. My bad here...I'm new to programming rails!

Comment: It's a learning process. :) In general, `:order` and `:conditions`, when given string arguments, interpret them as raw SQL, so keep that syntax in mind. If you need to do interpolation, you can use an array construct like so: `["foo = ?", bar]` and `bar` will be sanitized.

Answer (score 0):

And what exactly is the error you are receiving?

I think your error is from here:

```
default_scope :order => 'comments.created at sec'
```

Because `comments.created at sec` you can't have that field in DB